# Push and pull from repository

Tags: git, repository

I am an apprentice,
jajaja.
I am trying to perform a pull/push origin master from my master branch and I have this problem, someone who knows how to help me or if I have to configure something?

[Find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zsBu.png)

Comment: Merging the remote master?
how could i do that?

Answer (score 0):

`git status` at the end of your screenshot would have told you what to do. You have to [resolve the merge conflict](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line).

- Look into the files mentioned by `git status`, remove the conflict markers and fix the content.
- After that `git add` the files
- And `git commit` your merge
- now you should be able to `git push`

Comment: I will try and you will confirm